# how to only change a specific query params in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Suppose I have this url:
`/app/search?spaceId=**621cd16015**&resource_type=room&capacity=3`

and I want to update only the spaceId based on click, so the new URL will be:
`/app/search?spaceId=**14235ad**&resource_type=room&capacity=3`

I'm using the class component. I used the following code to change the spaceId. It works, but it also removes all the other parameters too.

```
this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/app/search",
      search: `?spaceId=${event}`,
    });
```

Comment: Did you try [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? Maybe with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)? There's also the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API).

Comment: @Andy i cant replace as the spaceId is dynamic. How can I get old spaceId everytime to replace.

Comment: You can switch to functional component and use `useQueryParams` hook.

Comment: @MohitKushwaha I cant i m on client project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object

```
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams('spaceId=spaceOldValue&resource_type=room&capacity=3');
  searchParams.set('spaceId', 'spaceNewValue');

  this.props.history.replace({
    pathname: '/app/search',
    search: searchParams.toString()
  });
```